# Документация по VirtualTreeView

Tags: c++, c++builder, treeview, radstudio

Возникла необходимость использовать компонент VirtualTreeView, но не могу найти справку/документацию/примеры использования его на c++.
Есть парочка примеров, но на Delphi.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где найти хоть какую либо информацию по этому компоненту на c++?

Comment: Что касается винды, поиск гугл -  "msdn treeview". Т.е. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference или русская версия https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference (даже есть на ломаном русском). Если есть старая делфишная справка, или старый офлайн 2005 года (шел в комплекте с 2005 студией) то там примерно то же самое только офлайн.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вы не совсем правильно поняли, я имел ввиду компонент VirtualTreeView, а не TreeView :)

Comment: Что это за компонент? Из какой он библиотеки? В стандартной библиотеке C++ нет такого типа.

Comment: @nick_n_a я уж заискался, по с++ вообще никакой информации нет

Comment: А это из растудии либа? У них в хелп-файлах должна быть инфа. Или чьё это?

Comment: @nick_n_a да, из рад студии, в хелпе что то есть, но там только делфи

Comment: Вот http://delphi.borlandforum.com/impboard/attach/0000098162/VirtualTreeview.pdf 9-тая ссылка с гугла))) Наверно лучше врядли что-то есть.

Comment: А на си++ тоже самое. Просто запись чуть другая, сишная.

Comment: @nick_n_a, попробую что-нибудь сделать, спасибо

Comment: Видимо вы используете какой-то сторонний компонент. Так что указывайте вендора и версию.